# Kubernetes python client: delete missing variable

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm trying to use kubernetes python client to manage my cluster, but I can't find how to update it without breaking things. My input is a generic list of micro services that I translate into kubernetes deployments and services.
At this point I generated a list of `V1Deployment` and `V1Service`. How to do the equivalent of `kubectl apply` with those objects ?

I tried this :

```py
def apply(self, api, cur_deploy_names: List[str]):
        from .kubernetes_impl import KubernetesImpl

        if self.deployment.metadata.name in cur_deploy_names:
            api.patch_namespaced_deployment(name=self.deployment.metadata.name,
                                            namespace=KubernetesImpl.namespace,
                                            body=self.deployment)
            logging.info(f"KUBERNETES: Deployment '{self.deployment.metadata.name}' updated")
        else:
            api.create_namespaced_deployment(namespace=KubernetesImpl.namespace, body=self.deployment)
            logging.info(f"KUBERNETES: Deployment '{self.deployment.metadata.name}' created")
```

The main problem here, is that if in my new configuration, there is just one environment variable deleted, for example, `patch_namespaced_deployment` don't update the deployment. Is there an efficient way to know if there is a difference between new and old config, and if so, use `replace_namespaced_deployment` if needed ?

I'm open to all answer because I'm really new to kubernetes api.

Comment: There is a "[force](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1beta1Api.md#patch_namespaced_deployment)" option for "patch_namespaced_deployment". Maybe it can help update deployment in any case. Another idea is to diff kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is live configuration and compare with new one, if there is difference, then patch it.

Comment: Thank, I try to use it but got this error: `"message":"PatchOptions.meta.k8s.io \"\" is invalid: force: Forbidden: may not be specified for non-apply patch"`. I dont know why, I'm searching on google at the moment.